# How to prevent a shortcut logging function from overriding lineno with python logging?

Tags: python, logging

Suppose I needed to systematically add some extra information for a logger, and that this logger would then be used in some classes.

I would use a pattern that would look a bit like this :

```
import logging                                                                   

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)                                             
format_ = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(name)s: %(lineno)s] -- %(message)s'         
handler = logging.StreamHandler()                                                
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(format_))                                 
logger.addHandler(handler)                                                       
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)                                                    


class A(object):                                                                 
    def log_thing(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):                                   
        logger.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)                                        

    def do_something(self):                                                      
        # Some code here                                                         
        self.log_thing('Everything is ok')                                       


if __name__ == "__main__":                                                       
    a = A()                                                                      
    a.do_something()
```

However, if you run this code, you'll notice that the "lineno" will be displayed as the line where the actual code to "logger.info" is done (line 13).

Is there a simple way to prevent this behaviour, and print the linenumber of the code that called "log_thing" (the one at line 17) ? Or are "shortcut to logging" functions doomed to behave like this ?

Comment: Get rid of `log_thing`, always call `logger.info("Everything is OK")` directly. That's how `logging` module is meant to be used.

Comment: This is not an option, even though I agree this would be the simplest solution. I need to provide a lot of metadata to every log record (the actual code does much more than my example), and those metadata are all taken from the properties of the class that will do this logging, hence the use of a method.